# Having Problems creating a site with gatsbyjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I install Gatsbyjs using:

`npm install -g gatsby-cli`

It installs and then when I try to create a new site it shows some error.

I have tried `gastsby new gatsby-site` but it shows some errors:

> PS C:\Users\Klawnny\Dropbox\ecommerce with react> npm install -g
>   gatsby-cli C:\Users\Klawnny\AppData\Roaming\npm\gatsby ->
>   C:\Users\Klawnny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli\lib\index.js
>
> > gatsby-cli@2.7.53 postinstall
>   C:\Users\Klawnny\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\gatsby-cli > node
>   scripts/postinstall.js
>
> + gatsby-cli@2.7.53 updated 1 package in 46.004s PS
>   C:\Users\Klawnny\Dropbox\ecommerce with react> gatsby new lcoproject
>
> File C:\Users\Klawnny\AppData\Roaming\npm\gatsby.ps1 cannot be loaded
>   because the execution of scripts is disabled on this system. Please
>   see "get-help about_signing" for more details. At line:1 char:7
>   + gatsby <<<<  new lcoproject
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], PSSecurityException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RuntimeException

I expected it to create the project but it shows this.

Answer (score 5):

if you are using VS Code integrated terminal then a simple terminal setting will solve the issue.

1. Go to `File -> Preferences -> Settings` or use shortcut `Ctrl + ,` to open settings
2. In the serch bar, serach for `terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows`, then on the result click on `Edit in settings.json`
3. Then add the following setting in `settings.json` file `"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]`

Comment: This worked for me, I also commented out this code: "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes I got issues running Gatsby on Windows.
The way how I solved most of them was installing the Windows Subsystem for Linux. 
I really recommend you to do the same.
The installation is pretty easy, take a look [at this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10).

Comment: Thanks, but that's for windows 10, and I'm using windows 7

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me by using the powershell integrated console

- Use the Ctrl+` keyboard shortcut with the backtick character.
- Use the View > Terminal menu command.
- From the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P), use the View: Toggle Integrated Terminal command.
- gastsby new gatsby-site

Answer (score 0):

This helps me:

1. Open **Windows PowerShell** in **Administrator mode**.
2. Run `Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned` then type `Y`

Bump!!!

Run your Gatsby command again.

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten the same issue a few times. How I fix it on windows 10 with PowerShell:

```
PS:C:\ Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

more info on [Set-ExecutionPolicy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-7.2)

Answer (score -1):

Dude you have a typo. You typed `gastsby` instead of `gatsby`. Please be careful with the spellings.